# Why does PyQt4 crash ipython-notebook the second time a script is run?

Tags: crash, pyqt4, jupyter-notebook

I'm learning PyQt4 right now and made a little script which should open a "Hello World!" box.  It works the first time I run it, but the second time, the script does nothing and crashes the ipython-notebook kernal, which requires a restart.  I'm using the Spyder IDE in Anaconda, under Windows.  This is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import Qt,QtGui
a = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
a.setActiveWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow())
hello = Qt.QLabel("Hello, World")
hello.show()
a.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, after a bunch of searching I found a duplicate question:
[simple IPython example raises exception on sys.exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888045/simple-ipython-example-raises-exception-on-sys-exit)

The solution, by Ali B, is to do this:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
```

before calling:

```
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```