# PyQt app.exec() seems to be non-blocking

Tags: python, pyqt, spyder

I have a quite complicated PyQt app (Qt5, running in Spyder), where at the end I do

```
def main():
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() 
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    status = app.exec_()
    print status
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(The if-else check is needed because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888045/simple-ipython-example-raises-exception-on-sys-exit)(second answer).) When I run this code, my app shows, and the status code `-1` is printed **at the same time** (due to a raised error in `spyder/utils/ipython/start_kernel.py`). My question is, why this error is printed at all, because I thougt that app.exec_() is a blocking call and the status is not returned until the app is exited somehow. Is this due to Spyder running its own `QApplication`?

Comment: What happens if you run `%gui qt5` before running your application?

Comment: Hi Carlos, I followed your advice regarding the issue I had before and changed the setting of the Ipython shell to automatic. Even if I run `%gui qt5` manually, the error remains (it's the famous `KeyError`, because `__file__` is not in `locals()`)

Comment: @CarlosCordoba is there already an open issue, regarding the underlying error? Or is this more like a non-issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to execute the application event-loop more than once. This is easy enough to test with a simple script:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Test')
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: print(QtWidgets.QApplication.exec_()))
btn.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
-1
```

So, if the event-loop is already running, `exec` just returns immediately without blocking.

(NB: obviously you will need to run the above script in a normal console to test it properly).

Comment: This makes totally sense. Thank you.