# Error Trying to initialize Dash in Spyder IPython Console

Tags: python, spyder, plotly-dash

I'm getting an error when trying to run a simple dashboard using Dash. I'm using Spyder with Python 3.4. I've `pip installed` `dash, dash_core_components, dash_html_compenents`..

My code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This was taken right from [Dash/Plotly website tutorial](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started)

I get the following error:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
C:\Users\mwolfe\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2889: UserWarning:

To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8050/` to try to view the example dashboard It won't load.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888045/simple-ipython-example-raises-exception-on-sys-exit/20292104#20292104) in order to fix the issue, but haven't been able to get that to work.

Comment: Have you tried to see the full traceback?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please open a bug in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) so we can try to fix/improve this in our side. I know why it happens, but I don't how Dash is generating this error.

Comment: If this is stunting your development you may want to try running your dash app from the command line. Also, per chance it helps, I documented my experience building a dash app (and deploying to Heroku) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47949174/3491991)

Comment: Try setting Debug to False. It worked for me.

Comment: @ScarletAndGray  Spyder gets hung up when i put debug= False

Comment: Maybe this got fixed in last few months, so in case anyone still having trouble. Setting Debug to False does indeed allow the tutorial example to display on Spyder 3.3.6

Answer (score 9):

Update on Pechi's answer: now setting debug=False works inside Jupyter Notebook as well. I tested Matt's code in there and the URL works fine.

However, I think the problem is mainly with the use_reloader. You have to set that to False in Jupyter Notebook (according to Plotly documentation). So, this also works in notebook for me:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
html.H1(children="Hello000")
)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False). <---- Here
```

Also, make sure any previous app you have initiated is stopped already (ctrl + c or simply use the square button in notebook (or press 'i' twice on your keyboard) for stopping the execution).

Answer (score 3):

Setting `debug=False` does solve the problem, but not with Jupyter notebook and Spyder. The code goes into limbo when executed with notebook/spyder.

**Change your code to `debug=False` and execute it in PyQt console** that comes with Anaconda Navigator. It works.

Comment: Yeah well but why? What if i want to run debug mode?

Comment: I believe debug=False lets your code changes reflect in the dashboard in real-time.