# How to skip permission error while deleting all files from a folder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shutil

I am working on a python script in which i am trying to delete all the files which are there within the given folder , though few errors like below are acting as a road block due to which the code is not able to complete.

```
PermissionError: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: C: \\users\\dhoni\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2735ad90-sfa3-412f-b6b1-54534646ff3.tmp'
```

my question is using shutil library how can i delete all the files from a specific folder or it is possible to delete files from two different folders ?

Tried the below code

```
`
import shutil
import os 
location = r"C:\Users\dhoni\AppData\Local"
dir = "Temp"
path = os.path.join(location, dir)
shutil.rmtree(path)`
```

Comment: a quick google I found this, `shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True, onerror=None)`. I don't actually know but worth a shot.

Comment: i have tried ignore_errors=True but that doesn't help, the files are still there

Comment: when you say the files are still there, is it just the files that had errors. Or does it fail to touch the ones that didn't have any errors too? If you don't have access to delete the file or it's locked for another reason then I don't think it'll be possible.

Comment: I found this too, maybe it can help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656322/shutil-rmtree-fails-on-windows-with-access-is-denied/2656405#2656405

Comment: not sure why but its not deleting a single file from that particular folder, i have tested it on my personal machine as well

Comment: can you test on a different folder that you definitely have access to? maybe it can't access any files in the folder. you could even have the app create test files, set one of the test files to read only (to force a fail) and then run the function. this test will demonstrate if it's permissions or code related. sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @eDonkey already wrote, `shutil.rmtree` only can delete folders not files. With `os.remove` you can delete files itself. The problem still is you dont have permissions. If you want to `force` delete everything inside that temp folder you can compile your code and run it as administrator. Problem with that is, that programs could crash when working with one of that file that got deleted. I experienced that with multiple programms (some of the programms where working with databases -> so pretty bad idea). I would advise not `force` delete the temp.

I already wrote some kind of code that is deleting the users temp. Its definetly not fancy but it works ;). Maybe you can copy some if it or get the idea of what it is doing.

```
import os, shutil, sys


def get_current_user():
    return os.getlogin()

def temp_deletion(user):
    error_count = 0
    error_list = []

    user_temp_path = f"C:/Users/{user}/AppData/Local/Temp"
    if os.path.exists(user_temp_path):
        for file in os.listdir(user_temp_path):
            file_path = f"{user_temp_path}/{file}"
            # Deletion for Files
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                try:
                    os.remove(file_path)

                except Exception as e:
                    error_count += 1
                    error_list.append(e)

            # Deletion for Folders
            elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
                try:
                    shutil.rmtree(file_path)
                except Exception as e:
                    error_count += 1
                    error_list.append(e)
    else:
        print("No tempfolder found!")
        print(f"{user_temp_path}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user = get_current_user()
    temp_deletion(user)

    print("Finished!")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: this code is running flawlessly on my personal system however throwing error on my office laptop

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Finished! An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback! systemExit

Comment: and this temp folder has normal folders, .TMP files, .dat files, .log files and .wbt files

Comment: try remove the sys.exit(). a quick research on a samilar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888045/simple-ipython-example-raises-exception-on-sys-exit)

Comment: what should this say me? `and this temp folder has normal folders, .TMP files, .dat files, .log files and .wbt files` is it not deleting the files?

Comment: nope this time it worked without throwing an error but didnt delete a single file/folder

Comment: did you compiled it and run it as administrator?

Comment: i need IT's approval to run it in administrator mode

Comment: i tried changing the path this time with C:\Windows\Temp, it deleted couples of files from this location but few folders are still unattended

Comment: then you can't force delete folders. It's like deleting any system files -> not possible without privileges. Mostly the reason for that is that a process is still using this folder/file

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't delete any files because `rmtree` deletes the entire directory, which cannot happen because *at least* one file in the directory is still used by another process. If you want to delete the directory, you'll have to make sure, that none of the files are used by another process.

Based on your question though, I'm making the assumption, that you want to delete the *files* inside the directory and not the *directory* itself.

To delete a file you'll have to use the `os` module, specifically `os.remove()` - the `shutil` module doesn't provide a function to delete files.

Which could look like the following:

```
import os 
location = r"C:\Users\dhoni\AppData\Local"
dir = "Temp"
path = os.path.join(location, dir)
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path)]

for f in files:
    try:
        os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
    except:
        print("Error while deleting file", f)
```

This will delete all the files *(which are not used by another process)* in the specified directory.

Comment: Hello Mate, Thanks for sharing this code this seems useful, however its printing error message for almost all the files means no file got deleted

Comment: i think its happening due to admin issue